# Validate an input and dropdown

Tags: jquery

Need some help to validate an input and dropdown. 
Both can be empty or both must be filled. 
If the user forgets to fill the text input in column 5 and select a value from the dropdown in column 6 alert message should appear 
or if the user forgets to choose from the dropdown in column 6 and fill in the text box in column 5 alert message must also appear. 
The validation must operate on each created row.

Check jsfiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/BE5Lr/4092/).

I'm thinking something like this:

```
  $('input[name=QtePack]').each(function (obj) {
        var $QtePack = $(this).val();
        var tr = obj.closest('tr');
        var $PackType = tr.find("[id^='Pack_Type_']").val();
        if ($QtePack.length > 0 && $PackType == '') {
            valid = false;
            $PackType.addClass('error');
        }
    });
```

[image]

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

see this demo http://jsfiddle.net/BE5Lr/4093/

```
  $('#SendButton').click(function (e) {
        // Validate if empty
        var valid = true;
        $('.required').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
                valid = false;
                $(this).addClass('error');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('error');
            }
        });

// changes starts

        $("input[name='QtePack']").each(function(){
            var ip = $(this);
            var sel =      $(this).closest("tr").find("select[name='PackType']");


            if((ip.val().length==0 && sel.val().length!=0) || (ip.val().length!=0 && sel.val().length==0))
            {
                     alert('enter both type and quant or leave both blank');
                     ip.addClass('error');
                sel.addClass('error');
            }
        });

  // changes ends  
        // Show validation alert
        if (valid == false) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('Some field(s) is required.');

            return false;
        }

    });
```

Comment: Thank Dev. I have fixed a small modification. valid = false; instead of alert() and added else{ip.removeClass('error'); sel.removeClass('error');}

Answer (score 0):

update your code as follows :

```
$('input[name=QtePack]').each(function (obj) {


    var $QtePack = $(this).val();
    alert("QtePack = "+$QtePack);
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');

    var reqelement=tr.find("[id^='Pack_Type_']");
    var $PackType = tr.find("[id^='Pack_Type_']").val();

    alert("PackType = "+$PackType);
    if ($QtePack.length > 0 && $PackType == '') {
        valid = false;
        $(reqelement).addClass('error');
    }

    if($QtePack.length == "" && $PackType != '')
    {
        valid = false;
        $(reqelement).removeClass('error');
        $(this).addClass('error');
    }
    if($QtePack.length == "" && $PackType == '')
    {
        valid = true;
        $(this).removeClass('error');
        $(reqelement).removeClass('error');
    }
});
```